# How to download and re-upload a repository?

Tags: github, repository

I'm new to using GitHub and most of the resources online are beyond my understanding.

A few years ago I had to commit certain labs and assignments to GitHub, and the repositories were in a "classroom." Forking is disabled on these projects. I don't remember much, other than that we cloned the projects and edited/pushed from Eclipse.

I've long deleted the local copies of the projects I had, and I'm hoping to showcase some of them on my profile. However, even after a few tutorials from GitHub, I don't know how I'm supposed to download the "classroom" repository locally and then re-upload it to GitHub on my own account.

When I download a zip file of a given project, I re-attain a local copy of the project. But when I try to upload it via GitHub desktop, there are issues. I can't upload folders, which is a problem. When I try uploading everything inside the folders, github desktop buffers for ages and doesn't finish the task.

It feels like my question is so basic that I can't find pointers on it, since it's taken for granted that people know how to do this. Any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just fork it from the "classroom" repository again if you're just trying to get the original project. Then you can git clone your forked repo.

If that isn't an option you can `git clone` the "classroom" to your local machine. And create a new repo on your Github where you want the project to eventually be saved. Then go back to the local project you cloned and push the local copy back to your new repo:

```
git push --mirror  <urlOfYourNewRepo>
```

Comment: thanks so much! Yep, forking is disabled- I think the instructors didn't want other future students to find answers to the same exercises if they just looked up the assignment.

when you say that I can git clone the classroom, do you mean that the classroom is a repository unto its own? Because my understanding is that the classroom is almost like a user, and the assignments and labs within it are the repositories. So should I clone each repo individually?